# Is selectedIndexes an Array type?

Tags: apache-flex

```
var google:Array = datagridID.selectedIndices;
```

Now is this equal to the one below.

```
var google:Array = ["0","1", "2"];
```

My problem is the above one its not taking as array, but when i define it like this it does.

Alert.show(google) gives me 0,1,2

```
for each(var i:String in google) {
Alert.show(dg.selectedItems[i]["member_id"]);
}
```

The above code yields me only one value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why first use the array of selectedIndexis and than use the array of selectedItems? Just use the array of selectedItems right away like this

```
for each(var item:Object in this.dataGrid.selectedItems){
    trace("Item: "+ ObjectUtil.toString(item));
}
```

In your case you can say:

```
for each(var item:Object in dg.selectedItems) {
    Alert.show(item["member_id"]);
}
```

And if you want the last selected item in the datagrid you do

```
Alert.show(dg.selectedItems[0]);
```

if you want the last item in the array of selected items you can do this

```
Alert.show(dg.selectedItems[dg.selectedItems.length -1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You made a typo. It should be datagridID.selectedIndices

It is the same, both are arrays. And I tested it and both should work. Hold CTRL and select a few lines in a datagrid and he should have an array of all the lines you selected. Always adding the last selected in front of the others. And why using google as variable name? It is not very describing what is inside the array.